# Spree Analytic Dashboard

Tags: spree

I have setup a new spree 1.0 application as per the documentation and i have hosted it on heroku. I have created account on spree-ecommerce for analytics dashboard credentials. But I didn't got any site_id[image]

I need guidance to setup analytics dashboard properly.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might want to try the spree-user Google group. It'll get a few more eyes on it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hardy12,

I just tried this for one of my sites and it worked okay. You'll have to email the user group or catch briandquinn on IRC. He's in Ireland, so you'll have to time it accordingly.

On a side note, if you're on 1.0 you shouldn't need to include the analytics gem. It should be built in.

Comment: it worked now for me also... As I changed currency type it did'nt work due to some unknown reason.. but now it is working... thanks..